# Scrapy Splash no funciona correctamente al sacar items cargados con JS

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, lua, scraping

estoy usando Scrapy con Scrapy Splash ya que algunas URL que necesito revisar cargan con JS sus componentes. Por ejemplo esta URL: [producto](https://www.tottus.cl/tottus/product/CASA-JOVEN/Hielera-Botellas-Metal,_/20420748) o esta URL: [producto 2](https://www.tottus.cl/tottus/product/KRYZPO/Papas-Fritas-Original/20261602) , de estas URL que son productos de supermercados, necesito sacar los 3 precios diferentes que traen:

[image: precios]

(Ojo que los precios van cambiando, hoy aparecen 3 precios en cada producto de las URL, pero puede que mañana ya sólo haya 1 precio o 2, o tal vez el producto no exista)

Tengo un Lua Script, el cual tiene un tiempo de espera y después de eso retorna el HTML:

```
script = """
        function main(splash)
          assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
          assert(splash:wait(4))
          return splash:html()
        end
"""
```

Lo ejecuto:

```
yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_item, args={'lua_source': script},endpoint='execute')
```

Y en mi función parse_item, tengo el response con el HTML y empiezo a buscar por XPATH:

```
price_strikethrough = response.xpath('//div[@class="price-selector"]/div[@class="prices"]/span[contains(@class,"active-price strikethrough")]/span[1]/text()').extract_first() 
price_offer1 = response.xpath('//div[@class="price-selector"]/div[@class="prices"]/div[contains(@class,"precioDescuento")][1]/text()').extract_first()
price_offer2 = response.xpath('//div[@class="price-selector"]/div[@class="prices"]/div[contains(@class,"precioDescuento")][2]/text()').extract_first()
```

Con esos 3 XPATH debería obtener los 3 precios, el problema es que algunas veces funciona y otras veces no funciona. Debo pasar el script de scrapy varias veces por las mismas URL, pero no funciona correctamente

No se que estará pasando, he aumentado el tiempo de espera pero es lo mismo, no tengo la seguridad de que saque los precios 100%, son muchas URL que tengo que revisar, pero si tomo 1 sola URL y le paso el script, puede que saque los precios todas las veces que lo ejecute, pero también puede que en el 99% de los casos los saque y 1% no lo saque, o puede que sólo lo saque 1 vez y las demás veces no saque nada. No se que está fallando, mi spider está correcto, ya que funciona y saca los precios. Pero algunas veces no lo hace y no se cual es el motivo. Como podré solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas parece que ciertas veces te bloquean la página, sería bueno saber que `reason` te da la página cuando no te sale nada. Un error 404, redirecciones 300, error del servidor 500, etc. Quedo una guía general de los principales problemas que puedes tener, así también puede servir a otras personas.

**Los principales problemas por los que puedes tener problemas en un scraping, si has realizado bien el parseo, pueden ser.**

- Ejecutas cientos de llamadas al servidor desde el mismo proxy. Solución, realizarla desde distintos proxys
- Ejecutas cientos de llamadas con el mismo header. Solución, cambiar el header dinámicamente
- Realizas varias peticiones por segundos y te bloquea el servidor al no tener un comportamiento "humano". Solución, poner un tiempo de espera
- Te aparece un Captcha. Solución, implementar un captcha solver, o hacer un retry
- Trampas en la web: en ocasiones las webs crean links invisibles en la página para los humanos, pero que los bots las pueden ver. Eso hace que se den cuenta de que eres un bot. Solución, parsear tú código de forma más severa y quitando los links `invisible`

Estos son varios de los problemas más comunes que te encuentras al realizar web scraping, pero puedes encontrarte muchos más, cada página es un mundo, si algunos no te son familiares, te recomiendo seguirte formando y practicando. En concreto este problema, la extracción de precios de forma constante, suele ser de los más complicados

Comment: Hola, el problema de esto es que entra a la URL y obtiene otros datos que no están en JS, así que me da siempre un code 200.
El problema es ya con splash. Ya que antes yo no necesitaba esos datos entonces sólo usaba scrapy de manera normal, y obtenía todos los datos que necesitaba. Ahora al implementar scrapy splash debo obtener 2 tipos de datos, esos precios que están en JS, y otros datos más, como el nombre del producto, etc, y esos no están cargados con JS y siempre los obtengo. El problema es splash y los datos cargados con JS, algunas veces los obtengo y otras veces no, a la misma URL

Comment: Entiendo, lo siento pero no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre Splash para poder ayudarte, si ves que no encuentras nada, podrías probar con Selenium para renderizar Java.